How to create and download PDF file on the phone, OFFLINE APP
Can anyone help me? I need to implement functionality to create PDF file by using data from local storage and safe it on the device. I use redux toolkit async storage as database. The app is completely offline so I cannot use any server requests. Also I use html to create the PDF.
const downloadPdfOnPhone = async () => {
    const permissions = await StorageAccessFramework.requestDirectoryPermissionsAsync();

    if (!permissions.granted) 
         return;
  
    try {
      await StorageAccessFramework.createFileAsync(permissions.directoryUri, 'Journal-catheterization', 'application/pdf')
        .then(async uri => {
          // Writing PDF contents to a file
          await FileSystem.writeAsStringAsync(uri, html, { encoding: FileSystem.EncodingType.UTF8 });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
};

This function works well until I try to open the file, I get an error that the file is broken.
I tried the "share" method but I failed.
Any suggestions appreciated! I use Expo.
